# Wrong array indexing does not cause error

Tags: c, arrays, indexing, comma-operator

Consider the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int a[] = {1, 2, 3};

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        printf ("%i\n", a[0, i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Obviously, the one-dimensional array `a` is accessed like a two-dimensional array in for example Python. However, this code does compile with a `unused-value` warning. I expected it to produce an error, because I always thought this for is of multiindexing is simply wrong in C (See K&R page 112). To my surprise, the above code indeed prints out the array elements.

If you change `a[0, i]` on line six to `a[i, 0]`, the first array element is printed three times. If you you use `a[i, 1]` the second element is printed three times.

How is a syntactically wrong multi-index on a one-dimensional array translated to pointer arithmatic and what value of the result of `a[i, 0]` is unused?

And, yes, I know how to multi-index in C.

Comment: You're mixing up the comma operator (`a,b`) and multidimensional array indexes (`[a][b]`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comma here, is the [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator). It's not a multi-indexing (which ideally would have been of the form `[0][i]` or `[i][0]`).

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.17 (*emphasis mine*)

> The left operand of a comma operator is evaluated as a void expression; there is a
>   sequence point between its evaluation and that of the right operand. Then the right
>   operand is evaluated; **the result has its type and value.**

So, in your case,

```
a[0, i]
```

is the same as

```
a[i]
```

and

```
a[i, 0]
```

is same as

```
a[0]
```

Answer (score 8):

`0, i` is a valid expression in C. The comma is an operator that evaluates both operands and discards the result of the left operand. When used in `a[0, i]`, it is equivalent to `a[i]`. And `a[i, 0]` is equivalent to `a[0]`.

(Note that in function calls such as `f(a, b, c)`, the comma is an argument separator. This is a different part of the C grammar, and the comma is not an operator in this context.)